# Viewing a large production log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ssh

I have a 22GB production.log file in my Ruby on Rails app. I want to browse/search the contents over SSH without downloading. Is this possible? Are there any tools?

Answer (score 0):

22GB is a very large file so it would be risky for your server to open the whole file using any tools. I'd recommend to split the file into multiple parts and search in each part. For example, using this command to split your file into small chunks of 1GB.

`split -b 1GB very_large_file small_file`

Also, you should set [logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate) for your server to avoid log file getting too big.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for. Thanks